# Windows always opened between the two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, window-manager

I have KDE 5 and a second monitor. 
Every time I open an application, the window appears exactly between the two screens. How can I avoid this, and for example, either:

- Tell KDE to open the application on the screen where it was last time,

or:

- Tell KDE to always open the application on the first monitor,

so that nothing is split between the two screens?

Comment: That question does not involve the KDE5 window manager.

Comment: You are correct, I retracted my vote.